# Powershell substring doesn't work: "20151129".Substring(6,7)

Tags: powershell, substring

What am I missing?

This doesn't work:

```
"20151129".Length
"20151129".Length - 1
"20151129".Substring(6,7)
"20151129".Substring(6,"20151129".Length -1)
```

But this does work:

```
"20151129".Substring(0,3)
```

Even though I'm not exceeding ("20151129".length - 1), I'm still obtaining an error:

> Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length
>   must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length" At
>   C:\Projects\Support\Microsoft\Powershell\DateRegex.ps1:23 char:1
>   + "20151129".Substring(6,7)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Now I know. Honestly, I searched for answers. When I found my own answer, I posted the solution. You really have time to penalize other users?

Comment: I marked your question as a duplicate of another (already answered) question. There is no penalty in that.

Comment: You apparently took the time to identify a similar post, and then hit the down arrow, ignoring the fact that I had posted a solution. You can be technically right, and still so completely wrong.

Comment: FTR: I remembered answering a similar question, so I dug it up and closed yours, yes. That was about the same time you posted your answer and I hadn't seen your answer before closing the question. I did not downvote your question (yet). This is my final response.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind:

"20151129".Substring(6,2)